# How to implement a PropertyPage with the Eclipse e4 API?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4

With an Eclipse plug-in, using the 3.x API, it was possible to implement a property page for project-specific settings (e.g., *Project/Properties/MyPlugin/...*),with the help of the `org.eclipse.ui.propertyPages` extension point and the `org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.PropertyPage` dialog.

Is there an e4 approach to implement such a property page?

Answer (score 1):

There is very little support for this in a pure e4 application.

You can make use of the classes in the `org.eclipse.jface.preference` package which form the basis of the 3.x code - `PreferenceManager`, `PreferenceDialog`, `PreferencePage` (used for both preferences and property pages).

You will have to write your own code to add pages to the preference manager and display the properties dialog.

Comment: The problem is wider, the functionality from `org.eclipse.ui.ide` is not yet fulfilled with e4 facilities. Do you have Eclipse Bugzilla tickets regarding this scenario and things around? It will be easier to get it fixed if you can create or reference the tickets.

Comment: @AlexanderFedorov e4 is not intended to implement everything that Eclipse 3.x compatibilty mode covers. The lack of property page support is not a bug it is just not something e4 intends to cover.